# How to Optimize a Fetch Query in Laravel and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to fetch a list of cities that has more than 40,000 cities, My issue is how to optimize since my browser keeps being responsive when loading the cities.
In Laravel Controller I have,

```
public function getCities(Request $request)
    {   
   $query = $request->input('query');
    $cities = UsCities::where('CITY', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')->get()->pluck('CITY')->toArray();
    return response()->json($cities);
    }
```

and the ajax code

```
$.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: '{{ route("get.cities")}}',
         data: { query: $('#city-selected').val() },
        success: function (response) {
          townsTags = response;
          startAutocomplete(townsTags, "#city-selected");
        }
      });
    function startAutocomplete(availableTags, inputSelector) {
      $(inputSelector).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
      });
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to load those 40k rows at once? Or loading them 5 at a time is enough? Also, in a single row, do you need all the columns? Or do you only need specific columns?

Comment: @mr kenneth, when the user types in the input city to be loaded from the list

Answer (score 2):

If you want to optimize your search method when users type the city in the input field, you need to make the condition in your JS with the following:

1. Start the ajax only after the input character is more than **x** length. That way the SQL query will return more accurate data.
2. Start the ajax only after **y** milliseconds so that http request will not always execute, thus only execute when needed.

Below is the code that you can try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // create a timer variable for setTimeout
  var inputTimer;
  function handleInputChange() {
    $('#loading').show(); // much better add a loading somewhere so that users can see that something is happening

    // clear the timer variable for setTimeout
    clearTimeout(inputTimer);
    var cityVal = $(this).val();

    // start ajax when input is 3 or more character length so that it will not always submit a request to your backend
    if (cityVal.length >= 3) {

      // setTimeout so that it will only execute the ajax after 500 miliseconds where there is no more incoming changes
      inputTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        // swap console.log to your ajax
        console.log("Input value changed:", cityVal);
        $('#loading').hide(); // add inside 「success」 method of ajax so that loading will hide after executing irregardless of success or error
      }, 500);
    } else {
      console.log("please enter at least 3 characters")
    }
  }
  $('#city-selected').on('input', handleInputChange);
});
```

change 3 or 500 depending on when you want to start the execution.

Comment: Have not tested but it should be enough for you to start